# How do I convert this JSON code into YAML?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, converters

I am currently studying AWS. I'm creating a CloudFormation Template. And I'm stuck with this problem.

I need to convert this JSON code below into YAML and add it to a template.
And the converters in google say

> "Unexpected Token : In JSON At Position 10".

```
"Fn::Join": [
 "\n",
 [
 "#!/bin/bash",
 "yum -y update",
 "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward",
 "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/send_redirects",
 "/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j 
MASQUERADE",
 "/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables",
 "mkdir -p /etc/sysctl.d/",
 "cat <<EOF > /etc/sysctl.d/nat.conf",
 "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1",
 "net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 0",
 "EOF \n"
 ]
]
```

I need to then add it to this YAML code below.

```
  NatInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: !Ref AmazonLinuxAMIID
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref AppSecurityGroup
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: NAT Instance
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid (as the error message tells you). You need to enclose it in `{` and `}`, and you need to remove the line break before `MASQUERADE",`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I enclosed them ex) {"#!/bin/bash"},
 {"yum -y update"}, and removed the line break before MASQUERADE",. and still the same error message shows up.

Comment: No. You need to enclose *the whole thing* in a single set of braces, not each line. You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to check the JSON validity. (Reading up on JSON basics won't hurt.)

Comment: I'll read up on JSON basics. Thank you so much.